# How to return IDs on insert in mybatis and oracle with annotation

Tags: java, oracle, annotations, mybatis

I am trying the following in Java

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO USERS (ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES(USER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,#{name},#{age})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="ID", keyColumn="ID")
public int insertUsers(User userBean);
```

It should return the new genarated ID, but its returning "1" always even though its making insertion into table in a proper way.

Can any one have tryied this "Getting IDs in return or insertion in MyBatis(annotation) with oracle"

Comment: Have you tried the RETURNING clause that Oracle offers?

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml_returning_into_clause.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply But....RETURNING clause always returns a value which needs to be stored into some variable but i am using a single line insertion instead of having a Procedure for the same

Comment: Fair enough, best of luck solving the issue. :-)

Comment: it returns 1 since it modified 1 row. Check - executeUpdate on preparedStatement returns number of ros it modified. I don't think there is a good solution for your problem. I use separate method to generate new id, set it to domain and than save it.

Comment: Sounds good but dear i can't do it because i am working on a existing system & frameork and i can make such kind of changes.

Answer (score 4):

Read the [MyBatis Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf&can=3&q=Docs).

> The keyProperty is the field that MyBatis will set the key into by
>   getGeneratedKeys, or by a selectKey child element of the insert
>   statement.

So,  given a Pojo with a field "id" with get and set methods.  After the insert statement with the Mapper class is ran, the id field on the pojo will be set with the generated key value.

Comment: To show an explicit example: Say you have a `Student` pojo with an `id` attribute. Create your new student and call `studentMapper.addNewStudent(student);` Now `student.getId()` contains the auto number, not the return value from `addNewStudent()` - that will always be the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for your responses, but i have got the solution here it is.....

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO USERS (NAME,AGE) VALUES(#{name},#{age})") 
@SelectKey(statement="select STANDARDS_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL from dual", resultType = int.class, before = false, keyProperty = ID)
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="ID", keyColumn="ID")
```

now it will return the new created ID